# how to pass the value from shell script to pig script

Tags: shell, apache-pig, sh

Hi i am trying to pass the values from the shell script and passing in pig script.
here is my code.

```
for((;;))
do
echo "Enter the city name"
read cityname
echo "Enter the state name"
read statename
pig -param city = $cityname -param state = $statename -f mb_property_table_updated.pig 
echo "Do you want to run for another city"
read answer
if [ "$answer" = "yes" ]
then
continue
else
break
fi
done
```

but i am getting like invalid file path.i don't know where i am making problem.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Issue might be due file "mb_property_table_updated.pig" is not properly located or file is not present at all. Try following command: "pig  -f mb_property_table_updated.pig -param city = $cityname -param state = $statename"

Comment: I don't know `pig`, but it almost certainly wants a single argument for each `-param` option, like so: `pig -param city="$cityname" -param state="$statename"`, etc. The quotes are needed in case a name contains whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

If you to send a single parameter to your pig script then try like below

```
pig -p city=$cityname -p state=$statename  mb_property_table_updated.pig
```

if you want to send a entire file to pig script then you can call it like below

```
pig -param_file /user/cloudera/demo.cfg mb_property_table_updated.pig
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be path you are giving for your pig file.
Try to give complete path of your localsystem

```
/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/pig/bin/pig -param date=$rightNow -f /root/training/projectFolder1/pigscripts/pigtransfers.pig
```

Hope this will help you...